# How to use -filter parameter in Powershell

Tags: filter, powershell-3.0

I'm currently running a PowerShell (v3.0) script and I have some jpg files need tidy in a folder. I want to sort  the  files  by the  file creation date .but it doesn't work.

```
get-childitem -path $fipath\*.jpg|get-itemproperty -filter LastWritTime "2013/10/2"
```

the command get nothing besides err info.

I have tried many other methods but it doesn't work anymore how to use the parameter `-filter` in PowerShell anyone can gave a idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

> Get-ChildItem -path $fipath  -filter *.jpg |where {$_.LastWriteTime.Date -eq "10/02/2013"}

Comment: ho ho ！ thank you！It works well this time！I have tried like this：

Comment: ho ho ！ thank you！@Tarique Noorain It works well this time！I have tried like this：
'get-childitem -path $filepath -filter *.jpg|where{$_.creationtime.date -eq "2013/10/02"}' but it returns nothing . is it because the file property “LastwriteTime” not equal “creationtime” ？

Answer (score 0):

date format should be like  MM/DD/YYYY